# How to add hours onto Day of Year

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, contourf

I am working with oceanographic data in Python. I am currently trying to create a contour plot of time on the x axis, pressure on the y axis, and temperature as the contours. Right now I am trying to format the time array with values that I got from the data itself. The code I have only produces the day of the year without the corresponding hours added onto it. I need a way to add on 6 hours, 12 hours, and 18 hours to each day because the data came from profiles of the water column that ran 4 times each day, separated by 6 hours. There were 1260 profiles and i corresponds to the file for each profile.

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime, time
import time

i = 1
temp = numpy.zeros((1260, 1000))
pressure = numpy.zeros((1260, 1000))
time2 = numpy.zeros(1260)
for i in range(1, 1260):
    filename = '/Users/ryanschubert/InternProject/itp47final/itp47grd' + str(i).zfill(4) + '.dat'
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        data = open(filename, "r")
    else:
        continue
    depthcounter=-1
    text = data.read()
    data.close()
    text = text.replace('   ', ',')  #this line and the next 5 lines are 
    text = text.replace('  ', ',')   #fixing formatting errors in the code
    text = text.replace(' ', '')
    text = text.replace('NaN', '-98')
    text = text.replace(',,', ',')
    text = text.split('\n')
    for line in text:
        depthcounter=depthcounter+1
        if depthcounter == 1:
            if i ==1:
                words4 = line.split(',')
                year = int(words4[0])
                doy = float(words4[1]) - 1
                hour = int((doy - math.floor(doy))*24)
                t = datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1, hour=hour,tzinfo=utc) + timedelta(days=int(doy))
                time1 = t.timetuple().tm_yday
                timetemp = numpy.array([t + timedelta(days=j/4.) for j in xrange(1260)])
            else:
                time2[i] = timetemp[i].timetuple().tm_yday
                print(time2[i])`
```

The code currently returns values like this;

```
102
102.0
102.0
103.0
103.0
103.0
103.0
104.0
104.0
104.0
104.0
105.0
105.0
105.0
105.0
106.0
106.0
106.0
106.0
107.0
107.0
107.0
107.0
```

and so on...

I need help adding 6 hours to each previous day of year so that the array looks like-

```
102
102.25
102.5
102.75
103.0
103.25
103.5
103.75
104.0
```

and so on.

Comment: What is `i`? Is this inside a function? If so, how are you applying that function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a `timedelta` of `1/4.` day, you could add a `timedelta(hours=6)`.

Otherwise, since you know you want your time to increase in `0.25` increments, you could simply generate an array of floats from the get go.

Note that, on my version of python3, `timetuple().tm_yday` returns an integer, not a float.